# Should I be using lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

So at the moment I have a multidimensional array

```
string[,] items = new string[100, 4];
```

I then gather the needed inputs to put them into the array, and then display them in a listbox

```
items[itemcount, 0] = id;
items[itemcount, 1] = newprice;
items[itemcount, 2] = quant;
items[itemcount, 3] = desc;

listBox1.Items.Add(items[itemcount, 0] + "\t" + items[itemcount, 3] + "\t " + items[itemcount, 2] + "\t " + items[itemcount, 1]);
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

So then the user can if they want select an item from the listbox to delete that item. When it came to deleting an item I realized that an array is not suitable. So should I create 4 different lists and use the list.Remove method to delete them or is there a better way that I dont have to work on 4 different things, also the user is running an older computer with WinXP would i have to worry about performance with 4 different lists? Is there anything such as a multidimensional list?

Thanks heaps for your help

Comment: Try looking into `Dictionary<T, T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent List of instances of a class. Something like

```
class Item {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public double Price {get;set;}
  public double Quantity {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}

var myItems = new List<Item>();
```

Comment: This is a very good example of how Lists can help you out in this situation.

Comment: Ok so just one question, are they indexed? Am i able to go myItems[2] or something like that to get the second item? and then when it comes to deleting one do I loop through each one to find which index it is and and go myItems[2].Remove() or something?

Comment: @MosesIAmnt, yes. Please check out [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) that can easily be found by [searching for "C# list"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+list).

Answer (score 3):

With the amount of data you'll be working with you really shouldn't see any performance issues.

Any type of Collection whether it be a `List<T>`, `Dictionary<T, T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, or whatever you want to use, it will provide you with more functionality than an array will.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have one complex type, that you should put into a list.  Not sure if the names are right, but something like this looks like what you want.

```
public class InventoryEntry
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public double NewPrice {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}

    public override ToString()
    { 
           //return your specially formatted string here
    }
}
var items = new List<InventoryEntry>();
//add some items
//add them to your listbox
//etc...
```